# Почему у меня не получается среднее арифметическое значение?

Tags: java

```
int[][] arrays = {
        {25, 100, 12},
        {2, 3, 7},
        {85, 14, 24}
};
double average = 0;
if (arrays.length > 0) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
            sum += arrays[i][j];
            System.out.print(arrays[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    average = (sum / arrays.length);
    System.out.println("Average = " + average);
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. **Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны** для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 2):

Вы делите не на то число.

```
double sum = 0;
int count = 0; // размер массивов

for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    count += arrays[i].length; // добавляем размер каждого массива
    for (int j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
        sum += arrays[i][j];
        System.out.print(arrays[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
average = sum / count; // вместо arrays.length подставляем count
System.out.println("Average = " + average);
```

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне, то подобные ошибки возникают из-за излишней сложности кода. Если найти более простое решение, то и ошибиться будет просто негде. Я бы сделал так :

```
double average = Arrays.stream(arrays)
        .flatMapToInt(i -> Arrays.stream(i))
        .average().getAsDouble();
```

Попробуйте ошибиться в таком коде))

Comment: Еще одно упрощение: `Arrays::stream`

Comment: @ Олексій Моренець согласен,просто в таких ответах хотелось показать лямбду в явном виде , не для всех это очевидно, хотя лично мне вариант Arrays::stream тоже больше нравится